# Health retreats in Japan

Tags: health, japan, kyoto

I am looking for health retreats in Japan. Specifically places that offer meditation (not necessarily zen), healthy food, a relaxing environment and beautiful scenery. I would like to stay somewhere in the mountainous area around Nagano, or perhaps around Kyoto.

Can anyone suggest resources to help me in this search?

(Mods: I would like to tag this question with 'retreat' but do not have the points to do so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mount Kōya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_K%C5%8Dya) might fit those requirements. It's a town in the middle of the Kii peninsula, a 1.5 hour (very scenic) train ride from Osaka (so around 2 hours from Kyoto), a sacred place of Buddhism, and many of the temples offer lodging. Guests can join the monks in prayer and meditation and will be served a very tasty (and healthy) vegetarian breakfast and dinner. The surrounding mountains offer several hiking trails. The scenery is nice but mostly not spectacular (the mountains are not very high).

Comment: That's a great option. Thanks! Leaving the question open for a bit longer.

Answer (score 4):

Wikivoyage has a couple of meditation retreats around Japan:

http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Meditation_in_Japan